# Prove that the following surjection of the Cantor set onto unit square is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

Assume that $C$ is a Cantor Set defined in the following way:
$$C = \left\{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n} : a_i \in \{0 ,2\}\right\} \subset [0, 1] =: I$$
with induced topology.

I want to show that the following function is continuous:
$$
f: C \to I \times I
$$
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{3^n} \overset{f}{\mapsto} \left(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{2n + 1}/2}{2^n}, \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_{2n}/2}{2^n}\right)
\iff 0.a_1a_2\dots_3 \overset{f}{\mapsto} 
\left(
0.\frac{a_1}{2} \frac{a_3}{2} \dots_2;
0.\frac{a_2}{2}\frac{a_4}{2} \dots_2
\right)
$$
To do it by definition i need to show, that for every open subset $(a , b) \times (c, d) \subset I \times I$ the inverse image  $f^{-1}[(a , b) \times (c, d)]$ is open subset in $C$. But can I find the inverse image of this subset directly ?

**UPDATED:** Here is my attempt:
$$(0.x_1x_2\dots_2, 0.y_1y_2\dots_2) \in (a , b) \times (c, d) $$
Then the following inequalities hold:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{2^n} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{2^n} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{2^n}
$$
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{2^n} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n}{2^n} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{2^n}
$$
But then:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^{2n - 1}} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{3^{2n - 1}} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{3^{2n - 1}}
$$
And also:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{3^{2n}} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n}{3^{2n}} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{3^{2n}}
$$
So we can conclude:
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^{2n - 1}} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{3^{2n}} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{3^{2n - 1}} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{y_n}{3^{2n}} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{3^{2n - 1}} +  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{3^{2n}}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^{2n - 1}} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{3^{2n}} <f^{-1}(x) < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{3^{2n - 1}} +  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{3^{2n}}
$$
So $f^{-1}[ (a , b) \times (c, d)] = C \cap \left( \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^{2n - 1}} + \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{3^{2n}};\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{c_n}{3^{2n - 1}} +  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{d_n}{3^{2n}} \right)$ - open subset of Cantor Set in induced topology.

Comment: I see two immediate problems. One is minor: in your attempt you’re using $a$ for two different things, the left endpoint of an interval in $I$ and a point in $I\times I$. The other, however, is a real problem: from $a<x<c$ you cannot infer that $a_k\le x_k\le c_k$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z^+$. What if $a=0.01_{\text{two}}$, $x=0.10_{\text{two}}$, $c=0.11_{\text{two}}$? Then $a<x<c$, but $x_2=0<1=a_2$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for your comment. Can you please check my updated attempt?

Comment: Much better, and easier to read, too. You have a typo in the final expression, but otherwise it looks okay: you have the $b_n$ sum at the left end of the interval and the $c_n$ sum on the right end instead of the other way around.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott but why is it a typo ? In my definitions $a < x < c$ and $b < y < d$, and the final expression follows from the previous inequalities

Comment: Oops! You’re right. Apparently I’m not quite awake yet. Yes, it’s fine, and nicely done.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you for your help!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: In your proof you write $a = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{2^n}$ etc. Unfortunately the sequence $(a_n)$ is not uniquely determined by $a$. For example $1/ 2 = \sum_{n=2}1/2^n$.